# Updating old RMarkdown hugo website running into errors

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

It's been a few year's since updating my personal website: https://statsbylopez.netlify.com/

That site was built with what now appears to be an outdated Hugo theme (hugo-academic).

On a new computer, I've downloaded the same repo and went to make changes, but when trying to render the site, ran into errors.

```
blogdown:::serve_site()
```

Renders the following error

```
Launching the server via the command:
  C:/Users/michael.lopez/AppData/Roaming/Hugo/0.101.0/hugo.exe server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t hugo-academic -D -F --navigateToChanged
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: "C:\Users\michael.lopez\Documents\GitHub\mlopez\themes\hugo-academic\layouts\_default\single.html:1:3": execute of template failed: template: _default/single.html:1:3: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "header.html" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\michael.lopez\Documents\GitHub\mlopez\themes\hugo-academic\layouts\partials\header.html:9:10": execute of template failed: template: partials/header.html:9:10: executing "partials/header.html" at <.Hugo.Generator>: can't evaluate field Hugo in type *hugolib.pageState
```

It appears the original Hugo themes are outdated ([wowchemy](https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic)), but I also know changing themes is not recommended (see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/other-themes.html)).

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem as the one reported in [the **blogdown** Github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/704). I'm just copying the answer here:

If you have an old site with the wowchemy/academic theme that used to work, it shouldn't be too hard to make it continue to work. The only thing you need to figure out is *which Hugo version* you were using at that time. Then pin the Hugo version in `.Rprofile` (follow the tips of `blogdown::check_site()`). If you don't remember the version now, you may

- either view the HTML source of the old site and see if the Hugo version was written there (of the form `<meta name="generator" content="Hugo X.Y[.Z]" />`
- or browse the Hugo releases: https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases and guess the version released at about the same time as when your old site was created.

Then install that version of Hugo with `blogdown::install_hugo("THAT_VERSION")`.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- I tried 15 to 20 different Hugo versions (using `install_hugo("version")`, and made sure to pin the Hugo version in the .Rprofile. In all instances, the new site either did not generate, or did so without the same features as the old one.    How difficult is it to try a new theme and merge in the old pages?

Comment: I just looked at the HTML source of your website and you were using Hugo 0.37.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the docs. Or at least search them for "hugo.generator"
2. Understand you don't need Hugo.Generator.
3. Delete it.
4. See if it builds.